# Ошибка Invalid syntax VK API

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

[image: ОШИБКА]

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
def write_message(sender, message):
    authorize.method("message.send", {"user_id": sender, "message": message, "random_id:" get_random_id()})
token = "свой токен"
authorize = vk_api.VkApi(token = token)
longpoll = VkLongpoll(authorize)
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
        reseived_message = event.text
        sender = event.user_id
        if reseived_message == "Привет":
            write_message(sender, "Добрый день")
        elif reseived_message == "Пока":
            write_message(sender, "До свидания")
        else:
            write_message(sender, "я вас не понимаю")
```

Comment: Ошибку прикрепите! Там написано, где вызывается ошибка. И токен лучше удалите отсюда.

Comment: Согласен с @Sherlock прочитайте сами повнимательнее текст ошибки. Возможно (и скорее всего), там написано, где Вы ошиблись. Ну или, в конце концов, покажите текст ошибки в вопросе, потому что без него ничего не понятно.

Comment: под своим ответом в комментариях отписал пару пунктов, проверьте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробуйте

```
def write_message(sender, msg):
    authorize.method(message.send, {user_id: sender, message: msg, random_id: get_random_id()})
```

Кавычки были лишними

Comment: @Oblaparis еще насколько я помню, вместо `VkLongpoll` у вас, должно быть `VkBotLongPoll` и в `VkBotLongPoll` должно передаваться два аргумента, токен и `group_id`. Но это не точно. Да и при наличии русского текста, я бы советовал в самом начале файла `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- `